# GetResponse API set_contact_customs() with multiple campaigns

Tags: php, api, getresponse

can someone help me?

I'm using the set_contact_customs() GetResponse API function. It works, but can someone explain what happens when the same email address is subscribed in more than one campaign?

For example I want to set the field 'bought' with the string '3' for the user mail AT mail.com

If the user mail AT mail.com is subscribed in two campaigns, which campaign does the set_contact_customs() affect?

set_contact_customs() doesn't take the campaign as argument (documentation: http://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/api/1.5.0/Contacts/set_contact_customs ), so if you want to set a custom field only for one campaign how can you do?

I tryed this:

```
$result_set = $client->set_contact_customs(
        $api_key,
            array (
            'contact' => $ee_cont_id,
            'customs' => array(
                array(
                'name' => $param_name,
                'content' => $param_value
                )
            )
            )
        );
```

And it affected only one campaign, but not the one that I wanted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you add one email address to two campaigns, this will produce two distinct "contacts" with different CONTACT_ID.

set_contact_customs() doesn't take the campaign as argument, because one CONTACT_ID "belongs" to only one campaign.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it now, indeed the same customer with the same email address has different contact id in different campaigns.

So as I said here: [Getresponse API 2 (Adding Custom fields and contacts using PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486052/getresponse-api-2-adding-custom-fields-and-contacts-using-php/)

you should first call get_contacts with the desired campaign name or id, and the customer email address. Then the contact id you will get from there, you will send to set_contact_customs.

Good luck! :)